# Sum the cell from another cell in html using jquery and show result in another cell

Tags: html, jquery

I want to sum focused cell in a table from another cell of same row and paste result in a total column of that row.

Below is my code.

> alert($(this).find('#table tr td input#quantity').val());

But its not working as giving me Undefined/Nan Error in alert.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: can you please elaborate the question

Comment: Kindly check screen shot.

Comment: @greatmajestics hii, Unable to understand your query. Also none of the cells are selected here and also can you say where to display the total? I think that will help me to give a solution.

Comment: You have to convert the values from format String to Integer first, before you do math operations. Use method `parseInt()`for it.

Comment: I want to design a table in html and jquery which will be used for data entry. Quantity entered will be multipled with the rate and a total will be calculated on the spot in the table of html using jquery. there are multiple totals in a table so each should be calculated when the data is entered in the specific cell of the row.

Comment: "*below is my code*" - if that's *all* your code, then that's the problem - you need to have a context for `this` - so your code needs to run based on an event such as `input` event when the textbox value changes.  How you create that event will determine how it works - please include that code - ideally, include enough code+html to *reproduce the issue*.  See [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use CSS classes instead of IDs that will allow you to calculate a separate row and have any numbers of rows. An example of the total sum is also provided.

```js
$('#table').on('input', 'input:not(.sum, .total)', e => {

  const $table = $(e.originalEvent.currentTarget);
  const $row = $(e.target).closest('tr');
  
  const calcSum = (elem, from) => {
    const sum = [...from].reduce((sum, elem) => {
      const val = parseFloat(elem.value);
      return sum + (val === val ? val : 0);
    }, 0) || NaN;
    elem.val(sum === sum ? sum : '');
  };
  
  // calc sum of the row
  calcSum($row.find('.sum'), $row.find(':not(.sum)'));
 
  // calc total
  calcSum($table.find('.total'), $table.find('.sum'));
 
});
```

```css
input{
  max-width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input readonly class="sum" placeholder="Sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input></td>
    <td><input readonly class="sum" placeholder="Sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input readonly class="total" placeholder="Total"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Input 1</th>
        <th>Input 2</th>
        <th>Input 3</th>
        <th>Input 4</th>
        <th>Input 5</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-box" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-box" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-box" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-box" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-box" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="total-input" readonly /></td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to update the total
  function updateTotal(row) {
    var total = 0;
    var inputs = row.find('.input-box');

    // Iterate through each input box in the current row
    inputs.each(function() {
      var value = parseFloat($(this).val());

      // Check if the value is a valid number
      if (!isNaN(value)) {
        total += value;
      }
    });

    // Set the total value in the last input box of the same row
    row.find('.total-input').val(total);
  }

  // Listen for input changes on the input boxes
  $('.input-box').on('input', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    updateTotal(row);
  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```