# live summing numbers from input fields and displaying it JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, element, event-listener

I am trying to figure out how to sum and display input numbers as live calculation.
It kind of works but the calculations are wrong. With each iteration it adds bigger number, like in arithmetic sequence. How do I solve this?

```js
"use strict";

let tot = 0;

let myInputField = document.querySelectorAll(".score");

myInputField.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("input", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < myInputField.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(myInputField[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(myInputField[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("total").value = tot;
  });
});
```

```html
<p><input type="text" class="score" id="myInputField12"></input>
</p>
<p><input type="text" class="score" id="myInputField13"></input>
</p>
<p><input type="text" class="result" id="total"></input>
</p>
</div>
```

Here's codepen: https://codepen.io/Bartosz-Spychaa-the-bold/pen/GRPNwYa?editors=1111

Comment: You're just not clearing the total sum, only ever adding to it. Simply set it to zero every time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum the cell from another cell in html using jquery and show result in another cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431335/sum-the-cell-from-another-cell-in-html-using-jquery-and-show-result-in-another-c)

Comment: Hey you can move the complete code from codepen to your question. I just tried it out and it works by using the snippet tool.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate and map/reduce

Also the HTML was invalid

```js
const scoreContainer = document.getElementById('scoreContainer');
const fields = scoreContainer.querySelectorAll('.score');
const totalField = document.getElementById('total');
scoreContainer.addEventListener('input', () => {
  total.value = [...fields].map(field => {
    const val = +field.value; // convert to number
    return isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
  }).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
});
```

```html
<div id="scoreContainer">
  <p><input type="number" class="score" id="myInputField12" /></p>
  <p><input type="number" class="score" id="myInputField13" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" class="result" id="total" readonly /></p>
</div>
```